# Not able to get Python Selenium to click a tabmenu using xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, ui-automation

[HTML of the webpage I am trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdOWB.png)

I am trying to click the Link called 'Network'. I used the following statements but I am not able to get to work as it throws me the following error:
[Error I get when I run the py script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ewK.png)

Here is the command I used:

```
eleme=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='maincontainer']//div[@id='tabmenu']//div[@class='tabmenu1']//ul[@class='tabmenu l1']//li[@class='tabmenu-item-network']//a[@href='Network']")

eleme.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath query is not good (href attribute is incorrect) so element can't be found, try with `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='maincontainer']//div[@id='tabmenu']//div[@class='tabmenu1']//ul[@class='tabmenu l1']//li[@class='tabmenu-item-network']//a[text()='Network']")`

Or even better, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='maincontainer']//a[text()='Network']")`

EDIT:
You can click on link with `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Network')`

You should really check WebDriver API http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Comment: I tried with the href attribute change (Both your methods). Still gives me the same error.
Is there any way other than xpath to click the networks tab? 

Not sure if this will help you in helping me-> I am trying to automate openwrt GUI and the HTML snippet I sent you was from openwrt GUI source..